# How should I input data from a Settings menu into the MainActivity.java file to adjust the size of the text in the Textview window?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drop-down-menu

all! I'm currently working on an assessment that's due in by tomorrow wherein I need to create a working application in Android Studio which features, amongst other things, a menu-adjustable option for the size of the text. The app itself is a 'quote-of-the-day' style application. Below is the code I've written up for the actual menu option.

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="14"
        android:key="edit_text_preference_1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Text Size"
        android:inputType="number"/>
```

While this works, and I am able to input a number into the settings area, I have no idea of how to link the value inputted through to adjust the size of my Text in the Textview window.

I apologize that this doesn't exactly follow the normal criteria, but I honestly have no results to show per se on this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreference for saving some value that will be used in another activity.

Here example based from documentation

To save:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.yourKeyStringName), yourValue);
editor.commit();
```

To read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValueIfKeyDoesntExist = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.yourKeyStringName), defaultValueIfKeyDoesntExist);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: So, to make sure I'm reading this correctly...

This piece of code should, in theory, take the number from the EditTextPreference as a setting, and then import that as the number for the size of the text in the MainActivity.java file?

Comment: SharedPreference should be to edit and get value data from saved string value in package res/values/strings.xml.
Because from your case, i think it's better for you to use SharedPreference instead.